# Solving $\left(\,x_s^a + y_s^a - (x_s - x_d)^a\,\right)^{1/a} - x_s + y_s + x_d = 0$ for $x_d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am working on a math puzzle, and I'm stuck at this equation:

$$\left(\,x_s^a + y_s^a - (x_s - x_d)^a\,\right)^{1/a} - x_s + y_s + x_d = 0$$

All terms are positive real numbers. What I have to do is to solve for $x_d$, that is, find a way to represent $x_d$ in terms of the other variables.

I noticed that $x_s - x_d$ is repeating, so I said to replace it with $z$:

$$\left(\,x_s^a + y_s^a - z^a\,\right)^{1/a} + y_s - z = 0$$

But that led nowhere. The equation doesn't look like a polynomial or anything that I know how to handle.

How can I solve for $x_d$?

Comment: Is $a$ an integer?  positive?

Comment: That implies $\,(z - y_s)^a+z^a-y_s^a=x_s^a\,$ which may be polynomial or not depending on $a$.

Comment: Hey @DavidG.Stork, sorry, I should have specified that. All terms are positive real numbers.